# Are skewed distributions problematic to binary classification models?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, normalization, standardization

I am trying to build a binary classification model and while trying to build the model, I have done some research about skewed distributions. I learnt that skewed models should be normalized to be tested for a proper statistical test, but I am not sure what effects skewed distributions have to the binary classification models.

And also, while doing my research on building binary classification models, most people I referenced tried data standardization as well as normalization for their skewed data distributions, but I don't know what benefits standardization and normalization will bring to building a binary classification model. I understand that we do standardization and normalization to suppress big numbers dominating the feature space hoping that those standardization and normalization can even bring skewed distributions to normal distributions, for example, log-transformation.

But I don't really have a firm understanding about the connection between skewness and normalization with a binary classification model but I kind of understand if I link the skewness with statistical tests. But when I try to think of the skewness in my dataset with my binary classification model, I cannot really get the clear picture what problems the skewness will bring for my binary classification model.

Notice that I am not talking about the class imbalanced dataset but I am only talking about distributions of features.

Answer (score 1):

The effect of skewness will differ between different classification methods.

Decision-tree methods are insensitive to the scaling of the predictors. Some suggestions for methods that are invariant with respect to monotonous transformations (e.g., log transform, squaring) of the predictors:

- Single decision trees based on the CART or MOB algorithms, which are implemented in the **`rpart`** and **`partykit`** **`R`** packages. The advantage of the latter is that it does not have a preference towards splitting on variables with a higher number of possible split points. Package **`partykit`** also implements the conditional inference tree algorithm, which is a good method, but it employs linear association tests for variable selection, which may be more sensitive to the scaling of the predictors.
- Decision-tree ensembles based on the previously mentioned tree algorithms, as implemented in the **`randomForest`** and **`mobForest`** packages. Or a CART-based gradient boosting decision-tree ensemble based on the previously mentioned tree algorithms, as implemented in package **`gbm`**.
- Prediction rule ensembles (PREs) based on MOB or CART. PREs aims to strike a balance between the ease of interpretability of a single tree, and the higher predictive accuracy of a decision-tree ensemble. This method is implemented in package **`pre`** (disclaimer: which I developed with Benjamin Christoffersen). Specify argument `use.grad = FALSE` in order to derive the rules using MOB, specify argument `tree.unbiased=FALSE` to derive the rules using CART (otherwise, default is to use conditional inference trees).

Normalizing or standardizing are linear transformations and will not mitigate skew:

```
set.seed(42)
skew <- 100*rbeta(100000, 2, 6) # generate skewed data
breaks <- seq(min(skew), max(skew), length.out = 20)
hist(skew, main = "Skewed raw", breaks = breaks)
norm <- (skew-min(skew)) / (max(skew)-min(skew)) # normalizes
breaks <- seq(min(norm), max(norm), length.out = 20)
hist(norm, main = "Normalized", breaks = breaks)
stan <- scale(skew) # standardizes
breaks <- seq(min(stan), max(stan), length.out = 20)
hist(stan, main = "Standardized", breaks = breaks)
```

[image]

Comment: All important here is the choice of the accuracy scoring rule.  Don't use a rule that requires Y to be balanced.  Use a strictly proper accuracy scoring rule.  See https://fharrell.com/post/classification

Comment: @FrankHarrell Skewness was in the features, I believe. Thank you for the link, this post should be required material for all 'data scientists'! I also prefer probability over classification models. In that sense, my randomForest suggestion is off. All others optimize a loss function as in logistic regression, or based on probabilities (CART).

Comment: Though I've seen significant miscalibration from random forests, you can get probabilities out of them.  Regarding skewness of predictors, that's not a big problem but I often symmetricize them before feeding into a cubic spline function.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Fully agree. But predictions of the individual trees are class labels, the RF's predictions reflect the proportion in each class. My comment about the randomForest suggestion being of is that I'm unsure if this is a good estimator for the probability, might be overconfident (i.e., closer to 0 or 1 than averaging over tree predictions).

Comment: I am not asking for a specific model but asking what effects skewness has for a binary classification model.

Comment: @StoryMay Ah, then my answer is not of use. The effect will largely depend on the type of binary classification model you are using / what statistical tests (thus my suggestions for above methods), so best if you specify that in you question. As an aside, normalization and standardization are linear transformations and will not affect skewness.

Comment: I am asking how skewness affects a binary classificaton model and why does linear transformations affect skewness?

Comment: @StoryMay Effect of linear transformation / normalization / standardization are added to post. Please add to your question _which_ binary classification model you are using, otherwise we cannot answer that question, because effect of skewness depends on method used. Therefore, I suggested methods above, where skewness has no effect. Also, as suggested by Frank Harrell, symmetricizing can be used to mitigate effect of skewness, but I have no advice on how to do that best